# PHP exec() use of memory

Tags: php, memory, exec

I can't seem to find a definitive answer for this one.

When invoking a shell command using `exec()` from PHP, does the memory that shell command uses count towards the memory limit that the PHP script is given?

I realise that if the command generates a lot of output, and that output is captured in the `$ouput` (second) parameter of `exec()`, then that returned data could blow the PHP memory limit. However, assuming all output is sent to a file, if the `exec()` command requires 128M of memory to run, should a PHP script with a limit of 64M of memory be able to run it?

```
<?php
exec('command_using_128M_memory >/dev/null 2>&1');
```

I'm assuming PHP5.3+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `exec()` command does not directly count towards the PHP since the process is executed separately not from within the PHP Process. Having said that if you use any output variable with the command they would count towards the limit.

So if you had a file which produced a lot of verbose logging, and you were capturing that logging it would count towards the memory limit.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected this may be the case, but needed to know for sure before relying on it. I guess PHP keeps track of memory that *it* directly allocates to a script, but does not care what memory any child processes request for themselves.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is correct. I have PHP running out of memory using exec() and not specifying a return.